# Using the Wayback Machine without loading scrolling images on its front page

Tags: archive.org

The Wayback Machine (https://web.archive.org) is very useful for finding old versions of websites. Unfortunately, its front page has a bar of horizontally moving images that take a long time to load. Even worse, I can't use the Wayback Machine over the remote desktop because the horizontally moving images take too much bandwidth and suffocate the remote desktop connection.

Is there a way to use the Wayback Machine without loading these scrolling images, or at least stop them from scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

### All you need is Adblock Plus and block the element:

### `web.archive.org###web_screenshots`

### ____________________________________________________________

[image: 0]

[image: 6]

### Result:

[image: 22]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can simply go to the front page of https://archive.org and it has a Wayback Machine search box, without the infinite scrolling images.